# Regular Expression to get strings enclosed in braces

Tags: php, regex

I want to get an array of the following types of strings:

data {string1} {string2} {string3} data

I want to get an array whose values are string1/string2/strin3. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

one-liner w/o capturing parentheses, the string resides in $stuff:

```
$arr = preg_match_all('/(?<={)[^}]+(?=})/', $stuff, $m) ? $m[0] : Array();
```

result:

```
foreach($arr as $a) echo "$a\n";

string1
string2
string3
```

Regards

rbo

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$data = '';
$matches = array();
if (preg_match_all('#\\{([^}]*)\\}#', $string, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER)) {
    $data = implode('/', $matches[1]);
}
echo $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "data {string1} {string2} {string3} data";
preg_match_all('/{\w*}/',$str, $matches);
echo $matches[0][0]; // {string1}
echo $matches[0][1]; // {string2}
echo $matches[0][2]; // {string3}
```

[PHP preg_match_all](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)